# Turn down webpage depending on time of day (DJANGO)

Tags: django, datetime, django-templates

How can i use django templates to remove the contents of a page depending on the time of day?

I'm creating an online food delivery site.  The delivery orders are sectioned off into times.

For example for a 7pm delivery drop, i would want the page to show normally until 6pm that day.  Then at 6:01pm i would want the page to say something like "This delivery time is not available"

Answer (score 1):

To be honest you shouldn't rely on template logic if you want to prevent unwanted behaviour.

You can create two variables, e.g.

```
from django.conf import settings 

TIME_OPEN = getattr(settings, 'TIME_OPEN', datetime.now().replace(hour=10, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0).time())
TIME_CLOSED = getattr(settings, 'TIME_CLOSED', datetime.now().replace(hour=21, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0).time())
```

In your url patterns you could add something like:

```
if TIME_OPEN < datetime.now().time() < TIME_CLOSED:
    urlpatterns += patterns('shop.customers.views',
    (r'^checkout/$', 'checkout'),
)
```

Based on your new variables you could add a context_processor that supplies a context variable to each template for UI logic, e.g. `{'shop_open': True}`.

Mind you these examples rely on server time, so you would have to check, because it can differ from your local machine. Another approach could be to create a decorator which can be wrapped around views that require certain times.

So, just to make sure; Don't rely on template logic, protect your views

Comment: Does datetime.now().time() will be returning the time of request and not the time of urls.py module initialization?

Comment: I agree that  the time logic should be removed from the template, but any comparisons to `datetime.now()` belong in the view, not the `urls.py`. The URL patterns are loaded only once, when the server is started. By putting the comparison in `urls.py`, `datetime.now()` will correspond to the datetime when the  `urls.py` module was loaded, not the time of the request.

Comment: @Alasdair I suggested a decorator as a view layer approach, I agree that's cleaner

Comment: how do you create a decorator?

Comment: have a look at the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/ and browse the django source code to see how they work